# AFNetworking accept all content types

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, content-type

I am doing a request operation to download every types of files from a server with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

At the moment, I am doing like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"image/jpeg", @"image/gif", @"image/png", @"application/pdf", ..., nil];
```

It is working nicely, but I would like to enable all content types possible to avoid missing some.

Is it possible to initiate the acceptable content types for every kind of existing content? Something like:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"*", nil];
```

Thank you.

Comment: The wildcard mime-type is `*/*`.

Comment: Seems not.
`[NSSet setWithObjects:@"*/*", nil]`
And the AFHTTPRequestOperation still returns me:
"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: image/jpeg"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just set acceptableContentTypes to nil.

the relevant code in AFNetworking looks like:

```
       if (self.acceptableContentTypes && ![self.acceptableContentTypes containsObject:[response MIMEType]]) {
        ...
```

if acceptableContentTypes is nil, then it doesn't bother checking, and just carries on downloading.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone who finds this needs to add a specific image MIME type to the acceptable content list you can do the following:

```html
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h>

AFImageResponseSerializer* serializer = (AFImageResponseSerializer*)[UIImageView sharedImageDownloader].sessionManager.responseSerializer;
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [serializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/jpg"];
```

We needed to support "image/jpg" MIME types and this worked perfectly.

Comment: Where is this supposed to be added? What Class?